# PInvokeStackImbalance when calling Delphi DLL from C# with pointer type

Tags: c#, delphi, pointers, dll

I am trying to call an externally - supplied DLL developed in Delphi from C#. However I always seems to get a stack imbalance error when calling the functions when attempting to pass a parameter of Delphi type 'pointer'.

Here is the definition provided by the developers of the DLL:

```
procedure SetSeparator( const aIsEuropean: Pointer ); stdcall; 
  external 'DLLName.dll';
```

My forward declaration in C# is:

```
[DllImport(EXPERT_RT_NAME, EntryPoint = "SetSeparator", 
      CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
public static extern void SetSeparator(string strSeparator);
```

The Code calling this in C# is:

```
string s = "1";
SetSeparator(s);
```

When called, the error received is:

> A call to PInvoke function '::SetSeparator' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

The calling convention is specified so I am pretty sure that's OK. I think the parameter is the issue?

I have tried changing the PInvoke marshalling, using IntPtr, and changing various options around the parameters. There is another (parameter-less) call that seems to work (but until I can initialise the DLL with this and a couple of other similar calls, I cannot be sure).

Also, I have some calls where I need to pass a pointer in order to received information also.

Hopefuly someone can help as I have spent alot of time resarching this already and despite following up everything I can see as relevant and running out of options.

I do not have access to source code for the Delphi code unfortunately.

Comment: The notation of "const Name : Type" in function parameter declaration means that Name is passed by reference. I.e. the function expects a pointer to pointer. Are you sure that you need to pass *string* (PChar in Delphi) to the function, and not a single byte, for example?

Comment: The developers of the DLL are fibbing. Their function does not have the signature that they claim.

Comment: @Eugene That's only true for data types that are larger than a pointer.

Comment: @David: Possibly the `CharSet`? I'm thinking Ansi/Unicode issue if the DLL is actually expecting a PAnsiChar and receiving something different. (I'm not that well versed with `PInvoke`, and agree the signature is probably different than documented.)

Comment: @ken charset would not lead to stack imbalance. C# string goes as pointer to char and that's the same size as Delphi Pointer.

Comment: @David, good point. I was thinking of it differently, but of course you're right. Thanks.

Comment: @David, thanks for the response and you were right... I 'found' a different (later) version of the DLL which worked for me. Many thanks for the confirmation that I was not in fact going crazy and to Ken and Eugene for your contributions.